# Decryption cipher java game

Tags: java

In my cipher game, I want the user to be able to decode the sentence one letter at a time, for example, if you type "ul" the letter " u" should be replaced with "l" in the sentence.

My code below replaces the letter but there are some errors. So this is the normal sentence: "The things out there that are unknown aren't scary in themselves. They are just unknown at the moment"
The code below results in this sentence "tphe tphings outp tphere tphatp are unknown aren't scary in themselves.
they are just unknown at the moment."

The ArrayList contains the sentences and "plaintext" just access each individually.

```
    public static void decryptString(ArrayList<String> arr,String input) {
    
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("\nEnter the number of the sentence you got again:  ");
    input = in.next();
    
    String plaintext = arr.get(0).toLowerCase();
    String plaintext2 = arr.get(1).toLowerCase();
    String plaintext3 = arr.get(2).toLowerCase();
    String plaintext4 = arr.get(3).toLowerCase();
    String plaintext5 =  arr.get(4).toLowerCase();
    String plaintext6 = arr.get(5).toLowerCase();
    
    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("1"))
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the letters you would like to substitute: ");
        input = in.next();
        
        String sentence1 = plaintext.toLowerCase()
                .replaceAll("t", input);
        
        System.out.println("Decoded: " + sentence1);
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: Why are you passing `input` if you're overwriting it via `input = in.next();` anyway? And what's the input for your "decoding"? Assuming you enter `tp` as per your description you'll end up with `replaceAll("t", "tp")` and if you read the documentation for that method it will replace all occurrences of `t` with `tp`. You probably want to extract the first 2 characters from your input instead and then call something like `replace(firstChar, secondChar)`.

Comment: Include the input and expected output.  I assume that the response to the prompt is `tp` and you are expecting the the output to be something like "tpe phings oup phere..."  If so, your input String contains the letter to be replaced (`t`) and the letter to replace it with (`p`).  When you do your substitution you are using the entire string (`pt`).  So you are replacing `t` with `tp` rather than just `p`.

Comment: @vsfDawg so How do i fix it? Can you give me some sample code of what it would look like ?

Comment: @IzabellaWnuk you can extract the characters from a String with the `charAt(int)` method.  For example, `char toreplace = input.charAt(0);`